# Angular - Input Date Format Binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I'm trying to bind my date inputs into milliseconds

I have quite a few inputs, so i'm trying to create a directive which looks like this

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('milliDate', milliDate);

function milliDate() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {

            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
                return data.getTime();
            });

            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
                var date = new Date(data);
                return date;
            });

        }

    };/* return */

};/* function */    

})();
```

HTML

```
  <input milli-Date ng-model='person.dateOfBirth'>
```

When I try to console.log (person.dateOfBirth) after a date has been inputted I get undefined.

Any thoughts?

Comment: try `milli-date` lowercase

Comment: The directive itself is working so don't think that's the problem.

Comment: It seems like once the filter happens it loses it's binding somehow.